# Whats the idea behind appfabric cacheing tags

Tags: caching, appfabric

I've been reading about appfabric caching. And one of the features is tagging cache entries. What would this be useful for? Some of the examples mention tagging products with their category and then using the tag to query for all products in the category. But I don't understand how this would work since I don't see how you can guarantee all products are actually in the cache making the whole query by tag things rather useless. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1):

To address your 'how you can guarantee all products are in the cache' point first, I think it's a completely valid criticism. When I've done demos of the tagging feature, I've loaded all the products into the cache when the application starts, tagging them appropriately - it's the only reliable approach I've come up with.

In terms of what tagging is useful for, I see it as giving you extra options for retrieving items from the cache. Remember that you can assign an `IEnumerable<DataCacheTag>` to each cached item, so to follow through with the products example, as well as the category you could tag each item with the supplier, or with things that go *across* the set of product categories such as 'FreeDelivery' or 'LowStock'.

Or depending on how you present it to the user, you could *drill into* a set of products, building up a set of tags to search the cache for e.g. begin with 'Menswear', then add 'Knitwear', then 'Colour:Black', then 'Size:L', showing a narrower set of products to the user with each tag added to the search.

Comment: yeah I understand what it does but I don't understand how it matches the cache aside pattern. Seems almost like a leftover part of a set of features that got scrapped. Let's see what vNext brings...

Answer (score 0):

Tags are one of the mechanisms you can use to categorize your cached items. This could be useful if you had a set of cache keys which contained data that was potentially interrelated. If you updated the data underpinning one of the keys, you would also need to ensure that the other keys were invalidated to ensure that consumers weren't being served inconsistent data from the cache. Another way to do this would be to create a cache region containing only the interrelated keys.